# why does 'got to ' mean 'must' in the present?

Tags: grammar

I was watching a video interview and met the phrase "I got to say", where *got to* was translated as must.Why are we not using *have to* here ,but get, and why is the past form used if we are talking about the present? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I got to say* is a elision of *I've got to say*. That's the history. Native speakers understand *got* in this context to mean *have got*, and therefore *must* is a proper translation. The past tense is not being used here; it is present perfect. When someone says, "I have got a cold," he means that he still has one. In this case, "I got to say" is "I have got to say", which refers to a present desire.

There's a great discussion on all this here:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76126/have-got-verb-form-and-tense

Comment: +1 The OP heard this in an interview. In writing rather than informal speech it would probably be "have to say", perhaps not eveb "have got to say".

Comment: @FeliniusRex Thanks a lot for your help ! :)

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks